# Desire2Learn Permissions to Access Semesters Via API

Tags: desire2learn

I am trying to use the Desire2Learn REST API to return semesters, but I'm getting a 403 Not Authorized error.

The request I am making is:
GET /d2l/api/lp/1.1/outypes/semester

I am making this call while authenticated to the system as a student user.

This is a test environment, so I have full control of the student user's permission, but I haven't found which permission setting controls access to the semester org unit. Is it possible for someone with lower level permissions to make this call?

What permission would this user need to be able to make this call?

Thanks!

Comment: I notice that you've specified version 2.0 in the route. The highest version for the LP routes is 1.4 so that may be your problem. You can do a GetVersions call to verify which versions of the APIs are supported in your environment.

Comment: There are a number of reasons you could be getting a 403 error. If you're using the route that you say (with the 2.0 version), then the fact you're getting a 403 to me indicates that you're not forming the call property with the right authentication tokens: that route shouldn't exist and so the fact that you're getting a 403 means that you're not even getting to the part of the process where the web service would try to find a handler for the URL you've used in your request... perhaps you have an invalid auth token here?

Comment: You may find it easier to take this issue to the discussion forum on Google Groups (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/valenceusers): to help you through this issue, you'll probably have to produce a trace showing exactly what HTTP call you're making and what the exact response is back ... this is probably a debugging session type issue, and not necessarily a simple, concrete question/answer (or, at least, answering the question you have may not, in fact, help you at all in this case).

Comment: @Sarah-BethBianchi, I mistyped my API version in the question. I will fix it. Thanks!

Comment: The solution I ended up with: since I just need a list of semesters for individual users, I am pulling the list of courses via the MyEnrollment call (/d2l/api/lp/1.1/enrollments/myenrollments), and then delving deeper into the course structure with a call to /d2l/api/lp/1.1/courses/{orgUnitId} for each course I pull. From there, I can get a list of terms for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Student-type user roles are not typically given permission to make calls like this one.

The particular permission at play here is likely `Org Unit Type Editor > Can Create and Edit Org Unit Types` at the root organization level (you'll notice that the same behaviour is at play around the API call to [retrieve the entire catalog of known org-unit types](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-outypes-)); however, you almost certainly do not want to grant this role permission to a student role: the role permissions for this tool bind together the ability to create and edit org unit types with the ability to see their definitions.